# Error Message: THERE WAS A P‌R‌O‌B‌L‌E‌M LOADING UPWORK

Tags: meter

Since last day I am getting issue(see link) with the Upwork. Many times I have reinstall the Upwork and restart the system but nothing goes happen.The network connection is also fine.I google but got nothing helpful. Anyone can suggested me how can I fix the issue. and make the Upwork run correctly.
As I remember the Upwork is running fine, I am getting the issue, since I run the command 'sudo restart lightdm' to display time on menu bar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link and steps to fix up-work issue.

https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Error-Message-THERE-WAS-A-PROBLEM-LOADING-UPWORK/td-p/83016/page/3

sudo dpkg -i libnss
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.19.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb

Upwork fixed.

Note : These issues we are getting if we do not close the up-work properly while shutting down the operating system. Please remember this things.